# session_regenerate_id() doesn't create session on multiple requests

Tags: php, php-5.5

We are regenerating session on each request in our application. When I click on menu for each request it creates new session and session file in `\tmp` folder.

But when simultaneously click on multiple menu it doesnt create new session and file.

We are using php function `session_regenerate_id(true)` to create session.

When I tried same function with false value `session_regenerate_id(false)` its working and doesn't logout on simultaneous request. What happened in this, new session is generated for only first and last request. For rest the request used first request session id.

Does it good to use `session_regenerate_id(false)` and prevent from session fixation attack?

Comment: PHP doc says: When session.use_trans_sid is enabled, output must be started after session_regenerate_id() call. Otherwise, old session ID is used.

Comment: Yes, it doesnt output anything before `session_regenerate_id()`